# How does tesseract separate mildly touching letters?

Tags: opencv, neural-network, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to implement a simple OCR engine with OpenCV and its Artificial Neural Network module.

I find it hard to segment touching letters, for example OpenCV considers "RX" as a single blob in the picture below:

[image]

I did try eroding the image but it'd tend to break characters apart (like the letter 'K'), while a high level of erosion is needed to separate R & X from each other.

However, when I threw the image into tesseract, it could read the letters perfectly. So how does tesseract preprocess and segment the letters?

Comment: If you only tried eroding, then you didn't try much :) Try searching for "OCR character segmentation" and you shall find dozens of papers dealing with the topic. ([example](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~elc/papers/pami96.pdf))

Comment: Hi, I know there are a various methods that are used to segment non-English text, but most of them are overkill. Given the simplicity of tesseract, it wouldn't be able to [recognize touching letter pairs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/MlNi0ypG8lI), however it still works for my case. So I'm wondering how tesseract achieves that without utilizing complicated methods.

Comment: I'm not sure "simple" is the right word. Some overview covering your question is in [section 4 of this document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/33418.pdf).

Comment: Ah that document is actually quite useful. Thanks!